# My java program output in apache netbeans is strange

Tags: java, netbeans

I just installed apache netbeans onto my laptop on which I have just re-install Windows. I wrote a simple program just to try the apache netbeans, but I'm sure there was something wrong here when I run the program.

My program :

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class latihanBaru {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     
        System.out.print("Your Name : ");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nYour name is : " + name);

    }

}
```

My Output :
[image]

It's supposed to show the sout result first, but I don't know what happened, can someone give me a hand for this? Thank you

Comment: Please [replace your image with the proper text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447)

Comment: Maybe try `System.out.flush();` before reading the text?

Answer (score 0):

[`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a ***autoflushing** [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)*. Printing a newline causes an ***implicit*** `flush()` but you can be explicit instead. Change

```
System.out.print("Your Name : ");
```

to

```
System.out.print("Your Name : ");
System.out.flush();
```

**or**

```
System.out.println("Your Name : ");
```

The linked javadoc says, in part,

> Optionally, a `PrintStream` can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the `flush` method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the `println` methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written.